# Установка расширения php

Tags: php

Понадобилось использовать расширение Rar для работы с соответствующими архивами. Выяснилось, что на локальном сервере (пользуюсь openserver, на windows) его нет. Пошла читать мануал на php.net, там нашла ссылку на скачивание dll. Скачала архив, файл php_rar.dll поместила в папку C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\ext , в php.ini подключила, сервер перезапустила. Но по прежнему класс не работает.
Что я делаю не так? Как подключить расширение?

PS: помогла замена библиотеки .dll на версию для x86

Comment: в phpinfo написано что нибудь про него?

Comment: нет, ничего

Comment: уточню, что после этих операций при перезапуске сервера вылетает пустое предупреждение: "PHP Startup:"
В остальном все как обычно

Comment: проблем может быть несколько:
1. Несовместиомсть версий РНР и php_rar.dll
2. Неправильно прописан путь к расширениям в php.ini

Когда вы подключаете стандартные расширения, они появляются в phpinfo?

Comment: да, появляются

Comment: В логах что нибудь есть ? Или при запуске ошибка или оповещение ?

Comment: при запуске появлялось пустое предупреждение. помогла замена версии .dll для x86

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\ext
```

А в настройках сервера стоит именно эта версия пхп или другая?
Ошибка может быть именно в неправильной версии пхп.

Comment: в настройках сервера версия 5.6, в phpinfo - версия 5.6.3

Comment: а лежат ли в опенсерсере еще папки с версиями пхп и какие...

Comment: 5.2 - 5.6 включительно

Comment: В папке 5.6 есть еще папки с версиями пхп?

Comment: нет, только одна версия в папке

Answer (score 1):

Я подозреваю, что вы редактируете не тот файл конфигураций.

Откройте файл

```
C:\OpenServer\userdata\config\PHP-5.6_php.ini
```

И пропишите в нем

```
extension=php_rar.dll
```

**UPD:** Сейчас скачал [php_rar-3.0.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/rar/3.0.2/php_rar-3.0.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip)

Поместил в `PHP-5.6/ext`, прописал в `PHP-5.6_php.ini` строку `extension=php_rar.dll` запускаю OpenServer.

Тестирую:

```
$rar = RarArchive::open('test.rar');
print_r($rar->getEntries());
```

Получаю массив элементов архива. :) Как видишь, все работает. (ОС Windows7 x64)

Comment: не в этом была проблема. В тексте вопроса, с меткой PS